# Maximum exposure of customer - splitting reported balance by reported month and dynamically assigning it

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a string of reported balance and reported months from credit info bureau. I want to calculate consumer's exposure by reported month. I have ~2 million records to process and I am looking for a solution in R.

I/P data:

```
df <- data.frame("id" = c(1,1)
,"reported_date_hist" = c("20170830,20170728,20170630",
                          "20170730,20170620,20170525")

,"cur_bal_hist" = c("12455,14085,16940",
                "0,1260,2467"))
```

o/p:

```
  id         reported_date_hist      cur_bal_hist
1  1 20170830,20170728,20170631      12455,14085,16940
2  1 20170730,20170620,20170525      0,1260,2467
```

i want an o/p as below:

```
df <- data.frame("id" = c(1,1)
            ,"c201708"=c(12455,0)
            ,"c201707"=c(14085,0)
            ,"c201706"=c(16940,1260)
            ,"c201505"=c(0,2467))
```

o/p:

```
  id c201708 c201707 c201706 c201505
1  1   12455   14085   16940       0
2  1       0       0    1260    2467
```

later I intend to group his balance in each month and take the max of it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is reported date and balance always comes as three records together. or it can be greater than or less than three as well?

Comment: June 2017 does not have 31

Comment: the balance can be reported for last 36 months on any day of the month. Idea it to get the balance of the customer in each month and then get his maximum exposure that he ever had in last 36 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea using `tidyverse`. We split the strings and `unnest` the data frame to a long format. We convert to datetime (`as.POSIXct`) and use `format` to get only year/month. We group on that, create a new variable with the `seq` of the length of each group (in order to avoid duplicate identifiers), and we use `spread` to convert to wide format, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 mutate(reported_date_hist = strsplit(as.character(reported_date_hist), ','), 
        cur_bal_hist = strsplit(as.character(cur_bal_hist), ',')) %>% 
 unnest() %>% 
 mutate(reported_date_hist = format(as.POSIXct(reported_date_hist, format = '%Y%m%d'), 
                                                                     format = '%Y%m')) %>% 
 group_by(reported_date_hist) %>% 
 mutate(new = seq(n())) %>% 
 spread(reported_date_hist, cur_bal_hist)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 6
>      id   new `201705` `201706` `201707` `201708`
> * <dbl> <int>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>
> 1     1     1     2467    16940    14085    12455
> 2     1     2     <NA>     1260        0     <NA>
> ```

**NOTE**: You can add `... %>% select(-new)` at the end to remove the variable `new`. Also `rename` can be used to change your column names if needed.

Comment: Haven't tried the above method but I notice that the May'17 balance of 2nd observation has shifted to 1st observation. I guess that will be a problem when I have multiple customers and need to group the balances at customer level (in the above case id).

Comment: What do you mean? There is only 1 observation for May '17

Comment: I tried to get 'tidyverse' installed on my office laptop but the installation is failing (may be due to R version, mine is 3.3.1) and thus I am not able to use the above solution. Is there any alternate way of doing it. Is it doable in base R?

Comment: I worked around using 'reshape2' package. After splitting the string, I unlisted them and then used dcast to transform them into wide format. Though this works fine with smaller data set I am not sure how it will behave when it has to transform around ~2 million rows from wide to long format resulting in ~5-6 million rows. I am going to give it a shot today by running it on a server. Hope this works.

Comment: Oh 2 million rows is not that big. I don't know why you can't install `tidyverse` though. I will try and add a solution with `data.table` which is even faster than `tidyverse` methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (have replaced id by los_app_id). 'data' is the dataframe which holds the raw data. Created a DFlong df by splitting and unlisting the result. Used a list of last 36 months to filter out the older reported balances. Used dcast of reshape2 package to get a month wise view of the total balances for each los_app_id (used sum to get the total). Now getting the max of these columns was easy.

```
DFlong<- data.frame(los_app_id = rep.int(data$los_app_id, sapply(strsplit(as.character(data$reported_date_hist), ','), length)), 
                yearMM = unlist(strsplit(as.character(data$reported_date_hist), ',')),
                bal    = unlist(strsplit(as.character(data$cur_bal_hist), ',')))

DFlong$yearMM  <-  gsub("","",DFlong$yearMM)

DFlong$yearMM <- format(as.POSIXct(DFlong$yearMM, format = '%Y%m%d'), format = '%Y%m')

last36months <- seq(as.Date(Sys.Date()), length=36, by="-1 month")
last36months <- format(as.POSIXct(last36months, format = '%Y-%m-%d'), format = '%Y%m')

DFlong$bal  <-  gsub("","",DFlong$bal)
DFlong$bal <- as.numeric(DFlong$bal)
require(reshape2)
DFwide <- dcast(DFlong, los_app_id~yearMM, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
DFwide$Maximum_Indebtedness <- apply(DFwide[2:ncol(DFwide)],1,max, is.na= FALSE, na.rm = TRUE)

result <- DFwide[,c('los_app_id','Maximum_Indebtedness')]
```